# Libreoffice crash

Tags: libreoffice

I updated libreoffice to 4.4.3 but it freezes and cursor movement are inverted.
I had to reverse back to 4.3.7 and it is OK.

Is the 4.4.3 buggy on Ubuntu 15.04 ?

Comment: How did you install 4.4.3 ? from libreoffice.org ? I have here 4.4.2.2 so I don't understand why you have 4.3.7 ?? How did you reverse back ? Libreoffice is available in ubuntu via it's software center.

Comment: install from here [http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/05/how-to-upgrade-to-libreoffice-4-4-3-in-ubuntu-15-0414-04/] and [http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-still/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a new LibreOffice configuration

```
mv ~/.config/libreoffice ~/.config/libreoffice.old
```

Comment: **reinstall from software center** and  **mv  ~/.config/libreoffice ~/.config/libreoffice.old**  solved the issue